# How to set path to opencv on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, makefile

I'm using mac os 10.10 and I need to build some code via make, but it give me an error

```
make
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -O3 `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o congealReal congealReal.cpp
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
congealReal.cpp:87:10: fatal error: 'cv.h' file not found
#include <cv.h>
```

but I have already installed opencv via brew

```
brew install opencv
Warning: homebrew/science/opencv-2.4.11_2 already installed
```

so how can I set up environment to opencv in mac os?

Answer (score 6):

I had a same problem and I solved it with the following steps.
First Update Homebrew.

```
brew update
```

Second Step: Install package config:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Third Step: install OpenCV if you didn't

```
brew install opencv@2
```

Fourth Step: Now you need to add OpenCV to your pkg-config

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv@2/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that might be helpful after you have installed `pkg-config`...

brew most likely installed your opencv to `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3`.

You might also have multiple opencv's installed (either through brew or source code, etc). If you run

`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

it might say
`-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_shape`
which indicates that the opencv that is being pointed to is not the one you installed with brew.

Therefore, replace the above with

`pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`

Adjust your brew directory and opencv version as necessary. This matters because packages could be different across opencv installations.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have `pkg-config` installed. 
Please do,

`brew install pkg-config`

This should remove the `pkg-config: command not found` errors.

After installing this, add the path of `opencv.pc` file into the `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file.