# using YOLO v3 on macOS: OpenCV don´t compile

Tags: python, macos, opencv, object-detection, yolo

I installed Darknet on my macbook pro 13" and I have done the steps as it says on the darknet website, but when I write in the MakeFile:
OPENCV = 1, I get this error:

```
$ ./darknet imtest data/eagle.jpg
    L2 Norm: 371.992218
    Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Original.png instead
    Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Gray.png instead
    Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C1.png instead
    Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C2.png instead
    Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C3.png instead
    Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C4.png instead
```

i do have Python installed as  well as OpenCV. i dont know if i need to set a Path or something or i am making something  wrong.
Can someone  please help me out?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add OpenCV to your path and then recompile darket. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975479/how-to-set-path-to-opencv-on-mac-os) post for adding OpenCV to path